# i am getting some data from local storage into a new page cart and it is showing all the data but in the layout, in the way i want

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Pleaase help me ....i am following a youtube video and i am creating cart and i am getting data from local storage and i want to show the data in the following way that
the "bookimage" and Name should be under the "TITLE"  price under PRICE  Quantity Under Quantity and total Under TOTAL... But i am getting things displayed under one another... as in the image attached shown[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okfp7.png)
when i use Display:flex; property i get all the result in one row like if i have 2,0r more results i want them in a separate row....Please help

## This is my Html

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <header>
      <div class="overlay">
        <nav>
          <h2>shop</h2>
          <ul>
            <li class="nav-item">                              
              <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCart" class="btncart" runat="server">CART<span class="cartspan" style="color:lightslategrey"> 0</span></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="products-container">
      <div class="product-header">
        <h5 class="product-title"> TITLE</h5>
        <h5 class="price">PRICE</h5>
        <h5 class="quantity">QUANTITY</h5>
        <h5 class="total">TOTAL</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="products"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script src="MyCustomJS/AddToCart.js"></script>
</body>
```

## this is styling

```css
.conatiner,.products-container{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin-top:50px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
}

.products-container {
  max-width:650px;
  justify-content:space-around;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
}
.product-header{
  width:100%;
  max-width:650px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  border-bottom:4px solid lightgrey;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.product-title{
  width:45%;
}
.price{
  width:15%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.quantity{
  width:30%;
  border-bottom:1px solid lightgrey;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.total{
  width:10%;
  border-bottom:1px solid lightgrey;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
.product{
  width:45%;
  max-width:650px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  padding:10px 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

## This is one of the JS futions

```js
function displayCart()
{
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('ProductsinCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    let productContainer = document.querySelector(".products")
    if(cartItems && productContainer)
    {
        productContainer.innerHTML = '';
        Object.values(cartItems).map(item => {
          productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="product">
              <img src="./imagesForCart/${item.tag}.jpg">
              <span>${item.name}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="price">$${item.price}.00 </div>
            <div class="quantity">${item.inCart} </div>
            <div class="total">${item.inCart * item.price} </div>`
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `.price !==pricce` so `<div class="pricce">` will ignore that css rule

Comment: yeah i changed it to price, but issue is not solved yet

Comment: `.products-container` is set to `flex` but the default `wrap` property is, I believe, `column` so inheritance is probably playing a part and forcing these elements into the column layout.

Answer (score 0):

i have changed

```
.products{
      width:100%;
        max-width:650px;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:flex-start;
        margin:0 auto;
        border-bottom:1px solid lightgrey;
    }
    .product{
        width:45%;
    }
```

and `<div class="price">$${item.price}.00 </div>`

Comment: thank you for your Answer but brother this takes all the rows  data into one row ....

Comment: you need to create working snippet for this, if you need quick result.